# PANDAS GroupBy Removing Header

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using the PANDAS groupBy and noticing it is removing the header name of the value I am running it on.

```
data = pd.read_csv("<CSV FILE NAME>", low_memory=False)
print data.head()
print data.columns
```

Gives me the following output:

```
        Store ID        Daily Sales
0       4444444         436
1       4555555          406
2       6435353         487
3       3421456          637
4       1111111         516
Index([u'Store ID', u' Daily Sales'], dtype='object')
```

When I run

```
data = data.groupby(['Store Number']).mean()
print data.head()
print data.columns
```

The output is changed to

```
                  Daily Sales
Store ID             
4166646        236.280394
4166663        152.061884
4166664        131.163746
4166665        144.920044
4166666        225.075027
Index([u'Daily Sales'], dtype='object')
```

The Store ID header name is being added as a value and removed from the header names. What is the reason behind this and is there a fix?

Comment: `data.reset_index()` is the key :)

Comment: @cel thanks, that solved it :)  I don't really understand what it is doing though.  When I run the groupby mean, why does it decide to remove the Store Id column?

Comment: The columns you group by are the new index of the result. that's why they seem to be lost. `reset_index()` removed this special index and makes them normal columns again. I am pretty sure there's a question/answer pair that explains this well. Probably someone of the python folks will link it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

set the as_index parameter to False.

```
data.groupby(['Store Number'], as_index=False).mean()
```

Comment: Thanks, indexing in pandas is confusing me

Answer (score 1):

Solved by @cel in comments adding in `data = data.reset_index()` after running groupby() added the header back